# Creating a random tree?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, algorithm, graph, graph-theory

What is a good way of creating a random tree (or an adjacency matrix that satisfies tree properties)? I currently have the following data structure that I am returning but I would like to generate this randomly. Any suggestions?

```
    return [{
        Source: "A1",
        Target: "A2",
    }, {
        Source: "A2",
        Target: "A3",
    }, {
        Source: "A1",
        Target: "A4",
    }, {
        Source: "A4",
        Target: "A6",
    }, {
        Source: "A4",
        Target: "A7",
    }, {
        Source: "A3",
        Target: "A8",
    }, {
        Source: "A3",
        Target: "A5",
    }];
```

Comment: When you say random.. Do you mean balanced tree?

Comment: @SajitKunnumkal: Actually, anything is fine. Preferably something which has more leaf nodes but other than that I don't really have any preference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A tree with n nodes can be uniquely expressed by a sequence of n-2 integer numbers (in the range of [0, n-1]). This is called the [Prüfer sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence).

Creating a random sequence should be no problem. Then you just have to transform the sequence to your tree structure and you're done.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for. I'm assuming that when you say `creating a random sequence should be no problem`, this is just an array of random integers and that there is no particular constraint that they need to follow. Is this correct? What I mean is if there is a way to control the depth of the tree that is generated.

Comment: Yes, there are not further constraints for the sequence (except the range of the entries). If you want to control the depth, you need to define what the depth of the tree is. After all you can set an arbitrary node as the root node. But beyond this there is no way to control the depth.

Comment: Correction : Numbers for the Prufer sequence have to be in the  range `[1, n-1]`

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya No, `n` has to be included. Consider the tree `1 - 3 - 2`. `1` is the smallest leaf, so `3` will be added to the Prüfer sequence. This range may be shifted depending on whether we use zero-based or one-based indices.

Answer (score 5):

Developing on the above idea, here is how we can generate a 20-node labeled random tree (in `python`):

1. start from a randomly generated length-18 sequence with each element chosen from the set {1,2,...,20}.
2. use the generated string as Prufer sequence for the spanning tree for the complete graph K20 on 20 vertices and generate the corresponding labeled tree (since there is a 1-1 correspondence always) using the following algorithm (from [here](http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/%7Ewcherowi/courses/m4408/gtaln7.html)).

[image]

The next code snippet implements the above algorithm to generate a labeled tree (by computing the edges) given the prufer sequence:

```
def get_tree(S):
    n = len(S)
    L = set(range(1, n+2+1))
    tree_edges = []
    for i in range(n):
        u, v = S[0], min(L - set(S))
        S.pop(0)
        L.remove(v)
        tree_edges.append((u,v))
    tree_edges.append((L.pop(), L.pop()))
    return tree_edges
```

Now, we can always generate a prufer sequence (of length n-2) randomly and subsequently generate the corresponding spanning tree (on n vertices), which can serve as our random tree (can be thought of to be randomly sampled from the set of n^(n-2) spanning trees of Kn).

```
n = 20 # Kn with n vertices
N = 25 # generate 25 random trees with 20 vertices (as spanning trees of K20)
for i in range(N):
    S = np.random.choice(range(1,n+1), n-2, replace=True).tolist()
    T_E = get_tree(S) # the spanning tree corresponding to S
    # plot the tree generated (with `networkx`, e.g.,)
```

The next animation shows a few such randomly generated labeled trees with 20 nodes.

[image]